# React Hooks - Modified state not reflecting immediately

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to refactor a class into a stateless component using `React` hooks.

The component itself is very simple and I don't see where I'm making a mistake, as it's almost a copy paste from the react docs.

The component is showing a popup when the user clicks on a button (button is passed through props to my component). I'm using `typescript`.

**I commented the line that fails to do what I want in the `hooks` version**

Here's my original class:

```
export interface NodeMenuProps extends PropsNodeButton {
  title?: string
  content?: JSX.Element
  button?: JSX.Element
}
export interface NodeMenuState {
  visible: boolean
}
export class NodeMenu extends React.Component<NodeMenuProps, NodeMenuState> {
  state = {
    visible: false
  }

  hide = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: false
    })
  }

  handleVisibleChange = (visible: boolean) => {
    this.setState({ visible })
  }

  render() {        
    return (
      <div className={this.props.className}>
        <div className={styles.requestNodeMenuIcon}>
          <Popover
            content={this.props.content}
            title={this.props.title}
            trigger="click"
            placement="bottom"
            visible={this.state.visible}
            onVisibleChange={this.handleVisibleChange}
          >
            {this.props.button}
          </Popover>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here's the `React hooks` version:

```
export interface NodeMenuProps extends PropsNodeButton {
  title?: string
  content?: JSX.Element
  button?: JSX.Element
}    
export const NodeMenu: React.SFC<NodeMenuProps> = props => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false)      

  const hide = () => {
    setIsVisible(false)
  }

  const handleVisibleChange = (visible: boolean) => {
    console.log(visible) // visible is `true` when user clicks. It works
    setIsVisible(visible) // This does not set isVisible to `true`.
    console.log(isVisible) // is always `false` despite `visible` being true.
  }      

  return (
    <div className={props.className}>
      <div className={styles.requestNodeMenuIcon}>
        <Popover
          content={props.content}              
          title={props.title}
          trigger="click"
          placement="bottom"
          visible={isVisible}
          onVisibleChange={handleVisibleChange}
        >
          {props.button}
        </Popover>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: `visible` is a constant defined in your component. There is no possible way that calling *any* functions could change its value.

Comment: Instead, `setVisible` triggers a re-render. When we render again, it will be set to a new value.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, but my jsx is being update but the value of constant in my function is not :( @DJ2

Comment: hi @Dan Abramov + 1, here, would flushSync() also work here?

Answer (score 12):

Much like setState, the state update behaviour using hooks will also require a re-render and update and hence the change will not be immedialtely visible. If however you try to log state outside of the handleVisibleChange method, you will see the update state

```
export const NodeMenu: React.SFC<NodeMenuProps> = props => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false)      

  const hide = () => {
    setIsVisible(false)
  }

  const handleVisibleChange = (visible: boolean) => {
    console.log(visible) // visible is `true` when user clicks. It works
    setIsVisible(visible) // This does not set isVisible to `true`.
  }      

  console.log({ isVisible });
  return (
    <div className={props.className}>
      <div className={styles.requestNodeMenuIcon}>
        <Popover
          content={props.content}              
          title={props.title}
          trigger="click"
          placement="bottom"
          visible={isVisible}
          onVisibleChange={handleVisibleChange}
        >
          {props.button}
        </Popover>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Any action that you need to take on the basis of whether the state was update can be done using the `useEffect` hook like

```
useEffect(() => {
   // take action when isVisible Changed
}, [isVisible])
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham, I can see the value updating now. However, since `isVisible` becomes `true` at re-render, I don't understand why the popover doesn't show up. I read the docs about useEffect, but I can't see why I need to use this for the popup to show up since `isVisible` does change to `true`?

Comment: you dont need to use useEffect. That was just an additional information

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri does this mean the change handler should be moved inside the `useEffect`  hook as well?

Comment: I too am facing a similar problem but didn't find the solution.