# React Context API - get updated state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am experimenting with React context api,

Please check `someComponent` function where I am passing click event (`updateName` function) then `state.name` value update from `GlobalProvider` function

after updated `state.name` it will reflect on browser but not getting updated value in console ( I have called console below the line of click function to get updated value below   )

**Why not getting updated value in that console, but it is getting inside render (on browser)  ?**

Example code

```
App function
    <GlobalProvider>
      <Router>
        <ReactRouter /> 
      </Router>
    </GlobalProvider>
```

=== 2

```
class GlobalProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "Batman"
  };
 
  render() {
    return (
      <globalContext.Provider
        value={{
          name: this.state.name,
          clickme: () => { this.setState({ name: "Batman 2 " }) }
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </globalContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default GlobalProvider;
```

=== 3

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
     const globalValue = useContext(globalContext);
     
    const updateName = ()=> {
           globalValue.clickme();
           console.log(globalValue.name ) //*** Here is my concern - not getting updated value here but , getting updated value in browser  
     }


     return (
    <div onClick={(e)=> updateName(e) }>
       {globalValue.name}//*** In initial load display - Batman, after click it display Batman 2 
     </div>) }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks - Modified state not reflecting immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428291/react-hooks-modified-state-not-reflecting-immediately)

Comment: It's always one tick behind the event loop, so you need to use an asynchronous call to make it work.  Simply wrap the console.log with a setTime() to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React state isn't an observer like Vue or Angular states which means you can't get updated values exactly right after changing them.

If you want to get the updated value after changing them you can follow this solution:

```js
class A extends Component {
   state = {
     name: "Test"
   }

   updateName = () => {
     this.setState({name: "Test 2"}, () => {
       console.log(this.state.name) // here, name has been updated and will return Test 2
     })
   }
}
```

So, you need to write a callback function for the clickme and call it as below:

```js
class GlobalProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "Batman"
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <globalContext.Provider
        value={{
          name: this.state.name,
          clickme: (callback) => { this.setState({ name: "Batman 2 " }, () => callback(this.state.name)) }
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </globalContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default GlobalProvider;
```

And for using:

```js
const SomeComponent = () => {
     const globalValue = useContext(globalContext);

    const updateName = ()=> {
       globalValue.clickme((name) => {
          console.log(name) // Batman 2
       });
     }


     return (
    <div onClick={(e)=> updateName(e) }>
       {globalValue.name}//*** In initial load display - Batman, after click it display Batman 2 
     </div>) 
}
```