# State value does not get not updated on first click but on the second click

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

I am trying to update my state value on my first click,

```
 const [Rating,setRating] = useState(0)

     const onRate = (nextValue, prevValue, name) => {

        setRating(nextValue)

        let variable = {
            productId:props.productId,
            userId:user._id,
            noOfStars:Rating
        };

        console.log(variable)
    }

  return(
           <div>
                  <h2>Rating from state: {Rating}</h2>

                                <StarRatingComponent
                                    name="rate1"
                                    starCount={5}
                                    size="5"
                                    value={Rating}
                                    onStarClick={onRate}
                                />
                            </div>)
```

[image]

The code that I have shown undergoes this procedure, when a user clicks on a star rendered using the StarRatingComponent the onStarClick method is executed. Where according to the package I have used provides a variable **nextValue** to set the new Rating by **setRating(nextValue)**. When I click on the star on the first instance the initial value of 0 is passed on the 2nd instance only does the correct value is passed. I want to be able to pass that value on the first instance. What needs to be changed in my code?

[Package I have used](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-star-rating-component)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks - Modified state not reflecting immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428291/react-hooks-modified-state-not-reflecting-immediately)

Comment: No sir I am unable to update the state using useEffect I tried it already

Comment: You don't need to update the state in an effect, I'm not sure where you got that from. You just can't expect the state `const` to change after calling a state updater. It doesn't work that way

Comment: Oh what should I follow then?

Comment: Move the console log into the component body, anywhere outside of `onRate`. You will see that it is indeed updated correctly, the value is just not available until the next render.

Comment: Ah yeah it works that way but I still am unable to pass the star value onclick

Comment: 1) That would be a separate question. 2) The code provided isn't enough to answer that, it will be based on the implementation of `StarRatingComponent`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-star-rating-component this is the implementation of StarRatingComponent, it is a 3rd party package I have used

Comment: Why are you binding `this` to the rate function? Its a functional component, and the rate function doesn't even use `this` (which it shouldn't).

Comment: That was a mistake of mine I recorrected it, how do you think I need to approach this, I still need to click twice to get the correct value

Comment: Its the same reason as listed in the linked duplicate: `Rating` will not be updated until the next render. But you're trying to use it to update `variable`. So `variable will always get set to the pre-updated value. Instead just use the parameter directly, `noOfStars: nextValue`

Comment: Thank you I will check on it