# React Hooks does not seem to be setting the data from the API

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have the following code to query a product database.

I have added console.log to event to check along the way.

```
function ProductSearch() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  async function handleSubmit(searchData) {
    const payload = searchData;
    console.log("Search Data:" + searchData);
    try {
      const response = await axios({
        url: `http://<domain>/Product/Search?keyword=${payload}&rowCount=10`,
        method: "get",
      });
      setData(response.data)
      console.log(response.data)
      console.log(data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

The first console log, when i type in cake shows Search Data: Cake
the response.data console log returns all the objects.
The data however, returns 0

I have tried doing just the total count, I have tried doing just one object.
What am I missing here as to why the data is not setting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks - Modified state not reflecting immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428291/react-hooks-modified-state-not-reflecting-immediately)

Comment: As the comment in the linked dup says: `data` is a `const` it **cannot** be changed. Plus, thats just not how state works (class based or hooks). The value will only be available on the next render. Log inside of the function body or within an effect to see its updated value.

Comment: AHHH thank you, seems stupid, i did not try to populate the data yet, i just wanted to see it come in first. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your data to state, React is just outputting a stale version of your state.

From my understanding this is just how React manages state (backend dev here, apologies for any bad terminology), if you run a console.log of state within the same function of you setting state, the function won't return the most recent version of your state, rather a "snapshot" of that piece of state at runtime of the function.

If you create a button that outputs your hook variable to console, and click that after setting state, you will get your most recent result.

It's a very big pain in the ass at where I work and hundreds of hours have been wasted dealing with issues of this sort.

Edit: Also you'll want to move your hook outside of your function, otherwise it won't be accessible to the rest of your file.